# Control Number Generation

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, vba

So currently I have the following.  When I click a button or hit submit button The form looks on the Ledger Tab.  I was trying to get the form to automatically generate a control number (ConNum) that looks like 135F16-01, where "F16" is the current fiscal year and the "-01" is the transaction number.  I wanted the form to search column A and generate the next available number.  To make it easier, or what i think may be easier, I built a RefInfo Tab and put control numbers in there.  So my thought is to have the form check Column A and use the next available or unused control number from a column in the RefInfo Tab.  Thoughts, input?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Dim emptyRow As Long

   'make Ledger active
   Ledger.Activate

   'Determine emptyRow
   emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = ConNum.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = FYSel.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = MoPBox.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = CHol.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = AO.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = ReqSec.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 8).Value = TranType.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 9).Value = VenNm.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 10).Value = PID.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 11).Value = TranTot.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 12).Value = TotBil.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 13).Value = TranTot.Value - TotBil.Value


If EOYNo.Value = True Then
Cells(emptyRow, 7).Value = "No"
End If

If EOYNo.Value = False Then
Cells(emptyRow, 7).Value = "Yes"
End If

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

'Set Control Number
ConNum.Text = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

End Sub
```

Comment: What result are you getting and what is the problem?

Comment: I know how to get it to look at one tab. 'make Ledger active.  But how do I get it to compare what is used on the Ledger Tab to what is available on the RefInfo Tab and display the next available on the Form "ConNum.Text = (next available)"